# Where can I find a list of gameplays?

Tags: game-mechanics, game-design

Long ago I found a website with a huge list of different gameplays; around 250 or so. I wanted to go back but right now I cannot find it (I've already spent some time on Google, believe me).

The site had a little picture with a brief explanation, that's all I remember.

I'd appreciate if anyone who rememebers the web site publish the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A list of game mechanics](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/a-list-of-game-mechanics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URL is: http://www.squidi.net/three/

Comment: Thanks!! I'm grateful someone helped on X-mas eve xD. Merry X-mas (in case you celebrate it).